# How to check JIRA issue id via Gerrit

Tags: plugins, jira, gerrit

I am building my gerrit server.
I have already used Jira by Atalssian (https://xxxx.atlassian.net)

I installed its-jira plugin in my gerrit server and set some configurations for gerrit.
I also created OAuth in jira admin settings.
(https://xxxx.atlassian.net/secure/admin/oauth-credentials)

The test connection has no problem.
But when I pushed my commit to the gerrit, the checking issue id has fail.
ARETC-1 is actually existed but push failed by this.
Anyone has some idea for resolving this ?

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/main    
Enumerating objects: 3, done.    
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.    
Delta compression using up to 8 threads   
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.    
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 295 bytes | 295.00 KiB/s, done.    
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0    
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done        
remote: commit 560621d: Non-existing issue ids referenced in commit message    
remote: The issue-ids    
remote:     * ARETC-1    
remote: are referenced in the commit message of    
remote: 560621db24a6713a9084cb8549f32285558da34a,    
remote: but do not exist in its-jira Issue-Tracker    
To ssh://review.xxx.net:5052/jira-test    
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/main (commit 560621d: Non-existing issue ids referenced in commit message)    
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://review.xxxx.net:5052/jira-test'
```